# Can I call 112 to check a police officer's identity in the Czech Republic?

Tags: czech-republic, officials

I'm travelling from the UK to the Czech Republic soon.

The UK foreign travel advice for the Czech Republic [includes the following](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/czech-republic/safety-and-security) (bold emphasis is mine):

> Beware of bogus plain-clothes policemen, who may ask to see your foreign currency and passport. If approached, don’t show your money, but offer instead to go with them to the nearest police station. **If you suspect that you are dealing with a bogus police officer, you can call 158 or 112 to check their identity.** No police officer in the Czech Republic has the right to check your money or its authenticity.

It is my understanding that 112 is an emergency number and checking a police officer's identity doesn't seem like an emergency. Is it acceptable to call 112 in this situation?

Comment: Theoretically, being scammed is an emergency. Because you could end up losing all your money/valuables, which is theft. If someone is being robbed here in the US, we call 911 as it's an emergency. I'd rather call than worry about if I should call or not.

Comment: The very likely reason why 112 is given is the fact that this number is universally valid in all European countries, for line and cell phones alike. That's incidentially the case _anyway_ in e.g. Germany or Netherlands, but in many other countries the "traditional" number such as 158 in this case is... whatever, something. Such as e.g. it would be 17 in France, 113 in Italy, and 117 in Liechtenstein. Or 93 in some part of former Jugoslavia. Which, frankly, no traveller can remember, being such a mess. 112 on the other hand "just works".

Comment: my uncle was scammed the same way as above in Spain, he lost all his money..

Comment: @Damon Regarding Germany, there was a previous question where 112 didn't "just work" and someone was directed to hang up and call 110 for the police (against official policy):
https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86440/67386

Comment: I have never met a bogus police officer in Czechia (I am a Czech), so I think you don't have to worry. I would rather watch out for dishonest taxi drivers or exchange offices. I recommend you checking the Honest Guide YouTube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt7oj318jVQi7vRbc1bNjJA

Comment: @RobertFurber `112` in Germany is dispatch for real emergencies (ambulance, fire brigade, civil protection). in case of fake police it is the best to directly dial `110`, because they can easily validate the ID; eg. on smart speakerphone. `112` might not always send the police, but when dialing `110`, they'll be there.

Comment: Is there a recent upsurge in such scams?  I travel fairly regularly to Czechia and had never heard of this nor been warned by the locals, at least in Prag, Olomouc and Brno.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Yes, but might be better to call 158.**

Pretending to be a police officer is a crime (at least in Czechia). If you suspect a crime, you're *expected* to call the police. Obviously, if you suspect that the guy standing next to you is a fake policeman, your property or health may be in imminent danger, so you're perfectly entitled to call the emergency number.

That said, the main emergency number for the police is **158**, so it's better to call that directly. **112** is an alternative number that connects you to the central emergency dispatch (actually operated by the fire department), which will in turn connect you to either the police (158), the fire department (150), or the ambulance (155), as appropriate. The result will be the same, but going through 112 will take somewhat longer.

However, unlike line 112, the national emergency numbers (150/155/156/158) don't guarantee English-speaking operators. If the operator doesn't speak English, you'll be simply connected to line 112. ([According to the police spokeswoman, in Czech.](http://www.centrumnews.cz/zpravodajstvi/tisnove-volani-cizinci-bez-obav-144679))

Comment: Thank you - that makes perfect sense. Does 158 guarantee English-speaking operators like 112 does? I'm learning some Czech but not enough to communicate well in an emergency

Comment: @LJD200 Good point. No, they're not guaranteed to speak English (unlike 112), but if they don't, they will just connect you to 112 to take care of you.

Comment: @TooTea would you then be redirected to 158 after speaking with 112? I.e. does this mean if you call 112 and speak the local language they redirect you to 158 and when you speak English they will not redirect you and deal with you on that line? Otherwise, it becomes catch-22 where you call the dispatch on 112, they identify you need the police and forward the call to 158 who then identify you don't speak the language and forward to 112...

Comment: @kiradotee I don't think it's that bad. In the linked Czech article, the spokeswoman for the emergency medical services says that "if the caller doesn't speak Czech, the operators of the line 112 help us in a conference call". I guess the police works the same way, so you end up in a three-way conference call with the police officer and a 112 operator, with the latter helping out as a translator. I don't have any experience though (and I'm not going to try calling 158 and pretending not to speak Czech just to find out).

Comment: If you have a scam artist/robber in front of you, no matter what number you call, 112/158 or whatever, will trigger a response from him. You could quite well call 123.

Comment: @PierreB I'm afraid that calling 123 is much less likely to get real police officers to the spot in time to help you. Or an ambulance.

Comment: @TooTea : I'm reasonably certain that, unless you are in a dark alley with not a single person nearby, if you call (or pretend to call) the police, the scammer will quickly go away and look for a different victim elsewhere. There is no reason for the scammer to take the risk. And if you *are* in a dark alley far from other people, and the robber would be willing to fight, there is no reason for him to pretend to be a police officer, he will just mug you straight away...

Comment: @vsz Sure, but it's still a good idea to report that incident to the actual police, so that they can do something about that guy.